# How can I convert a Word (.doc or .docx) file to a PDF on an iPad?

Tags: ipad, pdf, file-conversion

I would have thought this was one of Goodreader's many tricks, but it doesn't seem to be the case.

Answer (score 9):

If you have network access you could send it to Google Docs (upload, email, whatever) and then fetch the PDF from there.

Answer (score 8):

You could open it in [pages](http://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/apps-by-apple/pages.html) and then export to .pdf.

Source: Experience and [Apple Website](http://www.apple.com/ipad/from-the-app-store/apps-by-apple/pages.html)

Answer (score 4):

I went through this same hassle and it prompted me to write a [tutorial](http://www.3till7.net/2011/04/05/converting-a-word-docx-file-to-a-pdf-on-the-ipad/) on it.  A summary:

1. Preview the attachment in the Mail app.
2. Open the attachment from Mail into GoodReader.
3. Connect GoodReader to Google Docs.
4. Upload your doc from GoodReader to Google Docs.
5. Open up the Google Docs site in Safari.
6. Open your Word file in Safari in Google Docs.
7. Switch to the desktop version of the Google Docs site.
8. Download the file as a PDF.

Comment: While this may answer the question, [it is best](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to summarize the contents of the link and provide the link for reference. Links have a tendency disappear over time, leaving a non-applicable answer for those who may stumble upon your answer in the future.

Comment: Good call, @daviesgeek -- I added a brief description of each step.

Answer (score 3):

**Simple, local, free solution on the device - no online cloud services required**

The solution is to open the file in the App [Microsoft Word](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=624783) available in the Apple Appstore.
Then in the **[MS Word iOS App](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkID=624783)**, when the document is opened, goto **"Print" - "in another App"** and Word will convert the docx document to a pdf and open it in another app. (This seems to work even with the free readonly version of MS Word)

Comment: Simply the best way there is.

Comment: This is the answer. Print in the current version of Word on iPad allows you save as PDF so you don’t have to open it in another app.

Answer (score 1):

Get Notability - connect to Google Docs, it will convert on opening the file into a PDF all on your ipad, no need for a desktop.

Answer (score 0):

Tried the notability way. It worked. Thanks Anthony.

The steps I followed on iPad-

1. Download Notability (I already had it for work reasons. It costs $2.99)
2. Sync Notability to Google Drive
3. Open Word Document from email in Notability. It auto-converted the document to Pdf.
4. Email the document back from Notability to Email as Pdf.

Additional steps I followed since I needed to sign and date the document-

5. Open the document from email in GoodReader (Already had it for work
   reasons. Costs $4.99)
6. Sign and date the document in GoodReader and email to the recipient.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way to convert a Word Document to a PDF is to use [Word Online](https://office.live.com/start/Word.aspx), part of the free [Office Online](http://office.live.com) suite from Microsoft.

Once your .doc or .docx file is open, you just select "Download as PDF" and you have your PDF file.

This solution requires no 3rd party apps and does everything within the browser for free.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you have a .docs on a computer, upload to google drive, open it on iPad, download the file and follow the steps below on "If you are accessing a online .docs"

**If you are accessing a online .docs**

1. Open the file online on iPad
2. Hit share button on upper-right
3. Find print
4. After the print window pops up, pinch out (Like zoom out a map) on the preview
5. You will have a file now that is still named "SOMETHING.docs" but once you hit the share icon again and import it to another app, you will have a PDF file

**If you are using the word app**

Open the document, hit the "document with 3 dots" icon on the upper left, hit print, follow step 4 and beyond above.

Answer (score -1):

IPAD - How to change a .DOCX file into a word or PDF format so you can read it as if it were in WORD. First from the email you receive it from , Open the Doc., download it into  "drive" that's the Icon that is  shaped like a triangle, (the YELLOW , GREEN , BLUE icon). called "DRIVE" that's it! It will automatically download it as a .pdf so you edit it, move it, and view it better. From "Drive" you can Down load your now .pdf file into Word, Adobe etc. and rename it.

Comment: What is 'drive'?  What application is that?  My iPad doesn't have anything named 'drive' so can you please update your answer with more info?

Comment: Uploading a screen shot of what you are doing might help immensely. Without an edit to clarify the intent here, this is unlikely to help someone else.

Answer (score -2):

Easiest way that I've found if you're using the Microsoft Office App for iPad.

1) File
2) Print
3) Open in Another App
4) Import to iBooks
It will automatically save as a PDF file in iBooks. From there you can choose to print or email the PDF. You can also connect iBooks to your iCloud Drive and have it saved there as well.

Hope this helps! =]

Comment: This answer has already been given http://apple.stackexchange.com/a/245815/237